# Automatically have my frequently-used apps handy

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-nexus, launcher

I recently wiped and re-installed my phone. In so doing, I lost my home screen layout. In any event, my layout wasn't all that great.

What I'm looking for is an app/other method that would determine which apps I use most frequently and place them on my home screen automatically. I imagine this would need to be either a launcher or a widget. This way, I wouldn't have to spend time scrolling around for my most commonly-used apps.

Does such an app exist?

Comment: In year 2023, most of the answers are either dead or abandoned projects. Try [Frequaw](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jujinkim.frequaw&hl=en) which is recent and works by placing a resizable widget in your launcher home screen. With a few tweaks to the settings, you can make it look almost seamlessly similar to the regular icons you add to the home screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> determine which apps I use most frequently and place them on my home screen automatically.

There is [Smart Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.smartwidget).

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

[Cover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coverscreen.cover) is designed for this. It's a lock screen replacement app whose main feature is:

> **The right apps at the right time:** whether you're at home, work or in your car, Cover learns which apps you use and puts them at your fingertips.

Basically, it has a column of app shortcuts along the left side of the lock screen, which it dynamically changes to the apps you use mot often depending on your location and the time of day. Although this isn't quite the auto-homescreen layout you may have been looking for specifically, Cover's idea is that you shouldn't even *need* to get to your homescreen; it lets you launch your most frequently used apps directly from the lock screen instead.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [Arrow Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.launcher) automatically arranges your apps based on your usage.

Answer (score 0):

[Hanger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ca.mimic.apphangar) is another option I came across when looking for the exact same feature.

Main features from app description.

> - Auto-updating notification drawer shortcuts containing your most used    and important apps
> - Sort and display apps based on user specified weight factors
> - Pin apps to always display
> - Support for icon packs and custom icons
> - Optional second row of icons
> - Blacklist unwanted apps
> - Fully customizable! Change the number of shortcuts, icon color, icon    size, background and more.
> - Additional re-sizeable widget to launch apps
> - Re-sizeable widget to view app use statistics with color coded bar    graphs
> - Widgets intelligently scale according to size and device